# How could you give an intuitive explanation of the definition of the trivial line bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am trying understand what is the trivial line bundle in a manifold. There is an intuitive explanation of the definition? There is some basic examples that could help me understand that?

Comment: What definition are you using? Anyway, it is called trivial, because one possible characterization is the following: if $M$ is your manifold, then the trivial line bundle as a manifold is nothing but $M \times \mathbb{R}$. So, it is called trivial because you attached a line over each point in the "easiest way".

Comment: In contrast, the Moebius strip (without its border) is a nontrivial line bundle over the circle.

Comment: What is the definition of trivial line bundle that you are studying?